# Dead SD Card: How do I salvage the python virtual environment on my USB SSD Drive?

Tags: raspbian, python

Last week, my SD card died. I have a python virtual environment on a USB SSD that required a lot of work. Ideally, I'd be able to reactivate the environment, but it seems that none of my original packages are recognized as installed.

I realize that the recommendation before moving a virtual environment is to run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

I can't do that because all I have left is the SSD drive and a clean Raspbian. Is there any way I can salvage this environment without having to reinstall everything? There are several machine learning libraries that will be a pain in the ass to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if the device is the same. The point of a virtual environment is to be able to replicate it everywhere you need it.

Make a script that installs all necessary dependencies from a `requirements.txt` file and use it.

Use the command bellow to get the list of all python packages installed:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then install the dependencies in another virtual environment on another computer using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt`
```

If you want the exact environment, including system packages, on another computer, use Docker. Sources: [01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26399797/6602159) - [02](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24096/91830)